# batch files, variable expansion and substrings in loops

Tags: variables, batch-file, substring, expansion

I can't wrap my head around the variable substitution mechanism of DOS batch files, especially in for loops.

Simplified batch problem: imagine the following directory
01foo.txt
02foo.dir (this is a directory)
bar01 (this is a directory)
bar02 (this is a directory)

i want to move all files/directories in this directory that do NOT start with 'bar' to a subdirectory that is bar+_the_first_2_characters_of_the_filename_or_directory_name.
In this case, 01foo.txt would be moved into bar01 and 02foo.dir would be moved into bar02.

The following script is my first attempt:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion  
for %%A in (*) do (  
    set _x=%%A
    if (!_x:~0,2! NEQ "bar") move %%A bar!_x:~0,2!
)
endlocal
```

apart from the fact that this seems to loop only for files, it simply doesn't work at all :-).
I get an error in the if statement saying "3! was unexpected at this time"

Any idea on how to improve the situation/script?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It's only a problem of the syntax...

The `IF` statement does not expect not accept surrounding brackets.
The the comma in `!_x:~0,2!` breaks the IF-statment, you could quote both parts or move it into an own `set prefix=!_x:~0,2!"` line.
If you quote `"bar"` you also need to quote `"!prefix!"`.

That's all

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion  
for %%A in (*) do (  
    set "_x=%%A"
    set "prefix=!_x:~0,2!"
    if "!prefix!" NEQ "bar" move %%A bar!prefix!
)
endlocal
```